# How do I access a class variable from an extern "C" function?

Tags: c++, class, variables, extern

This is my basic code:

Here's the header file:

```
/** Include the necessary things **/

Class MyClass{
    private:
        std::string mystring;
    /**
     * Declare constructor, methods, yada yada yada
     **/
};
```

And here's the source file:

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
    mystring[0] = 0;
}

extern "C" MyClass::function(/* variables */){
    cerr << mystring << endl;
}
```

The problem, it seems, is that I get a segmentation fault on the  **cerr << mystring << endl;**  line. **function()** needs to be an extern "C" function because it's passed as an argument to a native C function.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This won't work... C doesn't know about classes and your method does not even have a return-value...

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: The C function would need to pass in an argument that represents the `MyClass` instance.

Comment: C may not be able to understand `std::string`

Comment: @ArunSaha C doesn't have to understand `std::string` -- that's not the real problem here.

Comment: A static function might work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Making a class member `extern "C"` is of limited usefulness, and I would suggest avoiding this method of exposing a C++ method to C code.

What you should do instead is create a wrapper function that takes a pointer to an instance of `MyClass` as an additional argument, and does the desired invocation:

```
extern "C" void MyClass_function(MyClass *obj, /* variables */) {
    obj->function(/* variables */);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Basically I need to pass function() to curl_easy_setopt() with a fixed number of variables. I'll have to do some more digging then, since using extern is a dead end.